# Not able to search for character name in Marvel API using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, express, async-await

I am using the Marvel API to get characters data. I am using axios to get this data, below is the code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const md5 = require('blueimp-md5');
const publickey = '73f5271b4d972dc0f4eba';
const privatekey = 'e9499a5ab5e65';
const ts = new Date().getTime();
const stringToHash = ts + privatekey + publickey;
const hash = md5(stringToHash);
sp = 'Spider-man'
const baseUrl = 'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/comics';
const url = baseUrl + '?ts=' + ts + '&apikey=' + publickey + '&hash=' + hash;

async function getMarvel(){
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return data; // this will be the array of people objects
}



module.exports = {
    getMarvel
}
```

routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const data = require('../data');
const marvelData = data.marvel;


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  
  try {
    const marv = await marvelData.getMarvel();
    res.json(marv);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const configRoutes = require('./routes');

configRoutes(app);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("We've now got a server!");
  console.log('Your routes will be running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

When the query string URL is:

```
'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters'
```

The data loads and works fine, but when I try to search it by name it does not work:

```
'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?name=Spider-Man'
```

It returns a 409 error, not sure what am I missing.

Output when I add name to Interactive documentation of marvel api:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "Ok",
  "copyright": "© 2021 MARVEL",
  "attributionText": "Data provided by Marvel. © 2021 MARVEL",
  "attributionHTML": "<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2021 MARVEL</a>",
  "etag": "79ef3436d0dc139b17693635b99776556e29f495",
  "data": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "total": 0,
    "count": 0,
    "results": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code stub in

```
const url = baseUrl + '&ts=' + ts + '&apikey=' + publickey + '&hash=' + hash;
```

make it `&ts` instead of `?ts` as continuing query parameters should start with `&`